# SQLite FTS4 external content using view without column names

Tags: sqlite, fts4

I'm using `FTS4` with `sqlite 3.8.10` and I'm trying to set up a schema like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (name TEXT);
CREATE VIEW TestView as SELECT name FROM Test;
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TestFTS using FTS4(content="TestView", name);
```

In this toy example, I have a simple table, `Test` and a view, `TestView`, which is equivalent to that table. I create an `FTS4` index, `TestFTS` from the view.

Then I populate some data as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('bob');
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('bill');
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('jane');
INSERT INTO TestFTS(TestFTS) VALUES ('rebuild');
```

So far so good. Now I want to query my data, for example:

```
SELECT name FROM TestFTS WHERE name MATCH "b*";
```

This should return two rows:

> bob
>
> bill

Instead it returns a single row and that row is blank. If I query all data from the `TestFTS` table then I can see the values, but obviously it isn't much use if I can't do `MATCH` type queries:

```
SELECT name FROM TestFTS;
```

> bob
>
> bill
>
> jane

Any idea why `SQLite` isn't returning the data, or even the correct number of rows, when using `MATCH` queries on external content `VIEW`s without column names?

====

UPDATE: I've tried using `sqlite 3.13` with named column views and I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2) says:

> When a users query on the FTS table requires a column value other than docid, FTS attempts to read the requested value from the corresponding column of the row in the content table with a rowid value equal to the current FTS docid.

So the view must include a unique column named `rowid` that corresponds to the FTS table's `docid`.

Comment: Beware: If you are using an External Content Table which is *not* based on a view, but on a normal table, a column named *id* is enough (as given by the examples on the SQLi

Answer (score 0):

The view needs a column named rowid. Id is not enough.
Beware: The examples on the SQLite website for [External Content Tables](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html#_external_content_fts4_tables_) are misleading:

```
INSERT INTO t3(docid, b, c) SELECT id, b, c FROM t2;
```

Using and id column works for a normal table, but not for a view. You need to use rowid instead:

```
INSERT INTO t3(docid, b, c) SELECT id rowid, b, c FROM t2;
```

Full console examples for linux with SQLite 3.11 based on the SQLite documentation examples.

Using a view does not work:

```
$ sqlite3 does_not_work.db;
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a, b, c);
sqlite> CREATE VIEW t2_v AS SELECT id, a, b, c FROM t2;
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="t2_v", b, c);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2, 'a b', 'c d', 'e f');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(3, 'g h', 'i j', 'k l');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t3(docid, b, c) SELECT id, b, c FROM t2_v;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3 MATCH 'k';
|
sqlite> .exit
```

But setting a column alias of rowid for id when creating the view works:

```
sqlite3 works.db;
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a, b, c);
sqlite> CREATE VIEW t2_v AS SELECT id rowid, a, b, c FROM t2;
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="t2_v", b, c);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2, 'a b', 'c d', 'e f');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(3, 'g h', 'i j', 'k l');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t3(docid, b, c) SELECT rowid, b, c FROM t2_v;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3 MATCH 'k';
i j|k l
sqlite>
```

Using a normal table works though:

```
$ sqlite3 also_works.db;
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a, b, c);
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t3 USING fts4(content="t2", b, c);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2, 'a b', 'c d', 'e f');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(3, 'g h', 'i j', 'k l');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t3(docid, b, c) SELECT id, b, c FROM t2;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3 MATCH 'k';
i j|k l
sqlite>
```